# Conditional distribution of order statistic of p-values

Tags: p-value, order-statistics

Suppose we have independent Unif(0, 1) random variables $\{p_1,..., p_n\}$. We sort them by $p_{(1)} \leq p_{(2)} \leq ... \leq p_{(n)}$. For $i \geq 2$ and $x \geq t$, I would like to compute

$$f_i(x) := \mathbb{P}(p_{(i)} \geq x \text{ | } p_{(i - 1)} = t)$$

My thinking is that this is the same as $\mathbb{P}(p_{(i)} \geq x \text{ | } p_{(i)} \geq t)$, in which case it equals
$$\frac{\mathbb{P}(p_{(i)} \geq x)}{\mathbb{P}(p_{(i)} \geq t)}$$
The problem then reduces to computing the distribution of the $i$th order statistic, and since the events $\{p_{i} \geq x\}$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli($1 - x$) we should have
$$\frac{\mathbb{P}(p_{(i)} \geq x)}{\mathbb{P}(p_{(i)} \geq t)} = \frac{\sum_{k = i}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (1 - x)^k x^{n - k}}{\sum_{k = i}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (1 - t)^k t^{n - k}}$$

Does this look correct?

Comment: It's not clear: you want the probability that exists _at least one i_ that verifies that condition, or the probabilty that _given an i_ it verifies that condition?

Comment: The parenthetical subscript refers to the order statistic. $p_{(i)}$ is the $i$th smallest random variable in $\{p_1,..., p_n\}$. So I want the probability that the $(i)th$ smallest is greater than or equal to $x$ given that the $(i - 1)$th smallest equals $t$, where necessarily $t \leq x$

Comment: If $p_{(i)}$ is the smallest variable, how can there be an ${(i-1)th}$ smallest? Anyway, if you are asking for a specific variable to verify that condition, than it's just the probability of a uniform random variable being greater than x divided the probability of it being greater than t: ${(1-x)/(1-t)}$

Comment: $i \geq 2$; it is a fixed index that is not one. For example, $i = 3$ corresponds to considering the third-smallest

Comment: Since variables are independent, $\mathbb{P}(p_{(i)} \geq x \text{ | } p_{(i - 1)} = t)=(1-x)/(1-t)$ $\forall  i\geq 2$

Comment: @Luke: the order statistics are not independent

Comment: The conditional distribution given $p_{(i-1)}=t$ is not the same as given $p_{(i)}\ge t$.

Comment: Hint: Write the joint density of $p_{(i-1)},p_{(i)}$. And derive the conditional pdf.